# Mod of two sites - close here or there?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

So, I have mod on both serverfault.com and webmasters.se - I've seen questions that are just plain wrong to be on Server Fault, and should be on webmasters.se, so I've migrated them there.

However, the question is really "too localised" to belong on webmasters.se - so I closed it after migrating it.

Should I kill it on the original site, or migrate it and then close it?

My thinking is the 2nd one, for the following reasons:

1. I won't always be a mod of both the sites, so I should act as if I'm not now
2. It leaves a clear audit path for the user to know why their question was closed
3. It leaves signposts for the next users who might ask totally off-topic questions

Thoughts?

Comment: @Benny - I was elected on SF in the most recent elections, and I'm still a pro-term mod on webmasters. I haven't decided if I'm going to run for webmasters.se yet "proper" election yet.

Answer (score 3):

Migrating and closing is just creating even more noise on the internet. I would close it on the *source* site and say "this is too localized, even for {target site}".

Comment: @far I had a bad typo in the original edit. Just to clarify, I *don't* support migrate-then-close.

Comment: no worries, I figured as much.